# Eliminar Duplicados de COALESCE SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql

TENGO UNA DUDA DE COMO PODRIA ELIMINAR LOS VALORES DUPLICADOS DE UN RESULTADO, YA INTENTE UTILIZANDO EL **DISTINCT** Y SOLAMENTE ME DEVUELTE UN VALOR Y ES EL ULTIMO DE TODOS LOS RESULTADOS

ESTE ES EL CODIGO EN SQL SERVER :

```sql
DECLARE @VALORES VARCHAR (1000)
SELECT  @VALORES=COALESCE(@valores + ', ','')+ B.PROVEEDOR
                FROM CONART AS A 
                INNER JOIN CONPRO AS B ON A.PROVEEDOR = B.PROVEEDOR
                INNER JOIN HH_ABASTECIMIENTO AS C ON A.ARTICULO=C.ARTICULO
                INNER JOIN ARTICULOS AS D ON D.ARTICULO=A.ARTICULO
                INNER JOIN PROVEEDORES E ON E.PROVEEDOR = B.PROVEEDOR
                WHERE A.CONARTSTA='A' 
                AND E.PROSTA='A'
                AND D.ARTSTA='A'
                AND D.ARTICULO='00000850'           
SELECT  @VALORES AS PROVEEDORES
```

ESTE ES EL RESULTADO QUE ME ARROJA :

```sql
PROVEEDORES
102284, 102284, 103404, 103404, 258050, 258050, 264801, 264801, 264802, 264802, 264803, 264803
```

YA QUE SOLAMENTE DEBERIA DE TENER 6 REGISTROS Y NO 12

ESTE ES EL RESULTADO UTILIZANDO EL DISTINCT EN LA CONSULTA

```
PROVEEDORES 
264803
```

SI ME PRODIAN APOYAR CON ESTA CONSULTA POR FAVOR

SALUDOS!

Comment: Cunado sumas null con una cadena, el resultado tambien es null. SELECT  @VALORES=COALESCE(@valores + ', ','')+ B.PROVEEDOR. Siempre retornará B.PROVEEDOR. Además,  imagino los registros están duplicados porque en alguna tabla hay dos registros que cumplen con la condición del join. Será abastecimiento?

Comment: Usa Group By B.PROVEEDOR, Saludos

Comment: En SO no se usan mayúsculas sostenidas. Por favor evítalo. Gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios ya intente utilizando el Group By , ya funciono a como lo requeria , lo pase por alto..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mira usa

> group by

```
DECLARE @VALORES VARCHAR (1000)
SELECT  @VALORES=COALESCE(@valores + ', ','')+ B.PROVEEDOR
            FROM CONART AS A 
            INNER JOIN CONPRO AS B ON A.PROVEEDOR = B.PROVEEDOR
            INNER JOIN HH_ABASTECIMIENTO AS C ON A.ARTICULO=C.ARTICULO
            INNER JOIN ARTICULOS AS D ON D.ARTICULO=A.ARTICULO
            INNER JOIN PROVEEDORES E ON E.PROVEEDOR = B.PROVEEDOR
            WHERE A.CONARTSTA='A' 
            AND E.PROSTA='A'
            AND D.ARTSTA='A'
            AND D.ARTICULO='00000850'   
 Group BY B.PROVEEDOR
 SELECT  @VALORES AS PROVEEDORES
```

Lo probé con una BD que tengo mira

```
DECLARE @VALORES VARCHAR (1000)
SELECT  @VALORES=COALESCE(@valores + ', ','')+ customer
            FROM so_header         
SELECT  @VALORES AS PROVEEDORES
```

Y me regresa repetidos

> 00017, 00017, 00017, 00017, 00020, 00020, 00020, 00020, 00020, 00020,
>   00020, 00024, 00025, 00025, 15000, 15000,...

```
DECLARE @VALORES VARCHAR (1000)
SELECT  @VALORES=COALESCE(@valores + ', ','')+ customer
                FROM so_header       
                group by customer    
SELECT  @VALORES AS PROVEEDORES
```

> 00017, 00020, 00024, 00025, 15000, ABBCOM, ABBLAB, BH V, C00100,
>   CATINC, FORMOT, GENELE, IBMCOR, IN HOUSE, JO, K, MOTINC, NE, NNN, PSM,
>   ZZ